# How to use returned json response in view - laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, json, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 + angularjs.

**GOAL :** Have to submit a form which have only check boxes. Based on the check box selected check box id fetch the data and return to the view. This returned data will be displayed in other div of same page.

**For Example :** Form is in div1 and returned data should be displayed in div2, div3 and div4. Only one division will be displayed on the view rest are hidden.

**FINALLY -** I am able to hide and display divisions using angular and I am able to submit the form which is in div1 using ajax. But I am unable to get the data back to the view from controller (data is returned in json format) and display on other divisions.

**How can I display the returned response json object on the view ?**

Below is my code :

**Route :**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

   Route::get('/form', 'PublicController@index');  // View will be displayed by using this method
   Route::post('/form','PublicController@show'); // Form is submitted and data is returned using this "show" method

});
```

**Controller :**

```
class PublicController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
    $crimetypes = crimetype::get();
    $step1='';$step2='';$step3='';$step4='';$step5='';
    return view('frontend.form')->withCrimetypes($crimetypes)->withStep1($step1)->withStep2($step2)->withStep3($step3)->withStep4($step4)->withStep5($step5);
   }

   public function show(Request $request, QuestionsRepository $questionsRepository){

        $data = $questionsRepository->returnSteps($request);

        $step1 = $data[0];
        $step2 = $data[1];
        $step3 = $data[2];
        $step4 = $data[3];
        $step5 = $data[4];

      // Data is successfully coming till here...

        return response()->json(['step1'=>$step1, 'step2'=>$step2, 'step3'=>$step3, 'step4'=>$step4, 'step5'=>$step5],200);

      // Here it is not allowing to use any other return type other than response json..
    }

}
```

**View :**

```
<div ng-show="div1">
        <div>
          {!! Form::open(array('method'=>'POST','url'=>'/form','id'=>'formid'))!!}
          <div class="col-md-12 row">
            <h2>Step - 1</h2>
            <hr>

            <br><p>Please select the relevant check boxes below.</p>
          </div>
          @foreach($crimetypes as $crimeType)
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input value="{{$crimeType->id}}" type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="checkid"> {{$crimeType->type}}
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          @endforeach
          <div class="col-md-12 row">
            <div class="form-group">
              <br>
              <hr>
              <input type="submit" ng-click="click1()" value="Next" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>
          </div>
          {!!Form::close()!!}
        </div>
      </div>

   <!-- On submitting above form hide the above div and display below div...this is working fine..-->


<div ng-show="div2">
          <div class="col-md-12 row">
            <h2>Step - 2 : Crime Details</h2>
            <hr>
            <h3>Can You Tell Us About The Crime</h3>
            <br>
            <h5><strong>@if (!empty($step1[0])) ? {{$step1[0]->question}} : ''@endif?</strong></h5>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control nbr" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxx">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <h5><strong>@if (!empty($step1[1])) ? {{$step1[1]->question}} : ''@endif?</strong></h5>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control nbr" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxx">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <h5><strong>@if (!empty($step1[2])) ? {{$step1[2]->question}} : ''@endif?</strong></h5>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                  <input type="textarea" class="form-control nbr">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <br>
              <hr>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <button ng-click="click2()" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-offset-10">
                <button ng-click="click2()" class="btn btn-primary">Skip</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

   <!-- Similarly there are three more div's where I have to display the fetched data...-->
```

**Script :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()
       }
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#formid').on('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var id = new Array();

     $('input[name="id[]"]:checked').each(function()
     {
       id.push($(this).val());
     });

     var $form = $('form');
     $.ajax({
       url:$form.attr('url'),
       type: $form.attr('method'),
       data: {id},
       dataType:'json',

       success: function(data){
         var step1 = data.step1;
         var step2 = data.step2;
         var step3 = data.step3;
         var step4 = data.step4;
         var step5 = data.step5;

      // If I use success, I am able to get data to these variables but unable to make use them on view wherever required. But now I am trying to use the returned object directly on the view without callback in the ajax. Even by using callback if it is possible, please help me out...
       }
     });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You can semplify the code in the controller I think, try to return directly `$data` as Json `return response()->json($data)`.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I solved this in angular way..........Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, here is the code I changed/added :

**AngularJs Files :**

**formCtrl.js :**

```
angular.module('formCtrl', []).controller('formController', function($scope, $http, Comment){

Comment.get().success(function(data){
    $scope.crimeTypes = data[0];
});
$scope.div1 = true;
$scope.div2 = false;
$scope.div3 = false;
$scope.div4 = false;
$scope.div5 = false;
$scope.div6 = false;
$scope.div7 = false;

$scope.selected = {};
$scope.click1 = function(data){

    var id = [];
    for(var i in data){
        if(data[i].selected==true){
            id.push(data[i].id);
        }
    }

    $scope.selected = {id};
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : '/index1',
        data    : $.param($scope.selected),
        headers :{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    $scope.div1 = false;
    $scope.div2 = true;
    $scope.div3 = false;
    $scope.div4 = false;
    $scope.div5 = false;
    $scope.div6 = false;
    $scope.div7 = false;
};

$scope.click2 = function(){
    $scope.div1 = false;
    $scope.div2 = false;
    $scope.div3 = true;
    $scope.div4 = false;
    $scope.div5 = false;
    $scope.div6 = false;
    $scope.div7 = false;
};
$scope.click3 = function(){
    $scope.div1 = false;
    $scope.div2 = false;
    $scope.div3 = false;
    $scope.div4 = true;
    $scope.div5 = false;
    $scope.div6 = false;
    $scope.div7 = false;
};
$scope.click4 = function(){
    $scope.div1 = false;
    $scope.div2 = false;
    $scope.div3 = false;
    $scope.div4 = false;
    $scope.div5 = true;
    $scope.div6 = false;
    $scope.div7 = false;
};
$scope.click5 = function(){
    $scope.div1 = false;
    $scope.div2 = false;
    $scope.div3 = false;
    $scope.div4 = false;
    $scope.div5 = false;
    $scope.div6 = true;
    $scope.div7 = false;
};
$scope.click6 = function(){
    $scope.div1 = false;
    $scope.div2 = false;
    $scope.div3 = false;
    $scope.div4 = false;
    $scope.div5 = false;
    $scope.div6 = false;
    $scope.div7 = true;
};

});
```

**formService.js :**

```
angular.module('formService',[])
.factory('Comment', function($http){
return {
    get:function(){
        return $http.get('/index1data');
    }
}
});
```

**main.js :**

```
var app = angular.module('angularApp', ['mainCtrl','formCtrl','formService'], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

No code change in Route and Controller files. In view only changed the div with checkbox class code to as shown below.

**Laravel Files :**

**View :**

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <input value="<%crimeType.id%>" type="checkbox" ng-model="crimeType.selected"  id="<%crimeType.type%>"> 
   <label for="<%crimeType.type%>"><% crimeType.type %></label>
</div>
```

**NOTE : I didn't used ajax script which I had posted in the question. Controller and Route files are not changed.**